# How can I make Jenkins jobs report all the changes since a given Git merge-base commit?

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, dvcs

In my Git repository, I have a staging branch where I merge a collection of topic branches onto the latest HEAD of the master branch.

I have a Jenkins job that resets the staging branch to master, merges each relevant topic branch into staging, and runs tests on the resulting staging HEAD.

In the job results, Jenkins intends to report the source code changes since the previous job. But it seems to get confused by this pattern where the commit IDs differ so significantly between jobs.

I think I'd like Jenkins to report all the changes since a given Git merge-base in each job.

Is there an existing Jenkins plugin I could use to do that? How?